# How to detect if a template is the homepage in EPiServer 5?

Tags: c#, .net, episerver

I've been asked to make a change to an EPiServer Template for an old system that is still using EPiServer 5. I need to know if the Template has been used as the site's home page. How would I work that out from the template's code?

I've tried this, but is dosn't seem to work as the PageStartId is different to the PageId:

```
var IsHomePage = page.PageId == EPiServer.Configuration.Settings.Instance.PageStartId;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to check if it's the startpage by comparing the reference with `PageReference.StartPage`, given that you have configured the startpage correctly.

`var IsHomePage = page.PageReference == PageReference.StartPage;`